# apparmor bind interaction, preventing jnl file updates

Tags: permissions, apparmor, bind

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Bind 9.18.18

I have placed by named zones files in /etc/bind/zones, but I have made the machine a secondary for dynamic DNS, it is a primary for static zones, though in actuality there are no clients since this server only exists to find zones or config file errors before moving changes to our actual primary.

I am seeing apparmor refuse to allow updates to the dynamic zone journal files.
I did not follow a good naming convention so these files have a variable number of periods in their names. I believe that allowing the bind user access to all files in this directory would be fine but I've failed to edit the apparmor usr.sbin.named file correctly, have not broken it, just failed to create the correct entry.

> Mar 11 19:23:59 intestclone audit[4414]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" profile="named" name="/etc/bind/zones/db.esp.38-ptr.jnl" pid=4414 comm="isc-net-0001" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=114 ouid=0

There is a secondary problem, when I reload the server I see this error: `zone cms155.wadsworth.org/IN: refresh: unexpected rcode (NXDOMAIN) from primary`

I have added this server's IP as authorized for transfers on the active primary/secondary servers. I don't believe this error is a result of the first problem, but I will solve the first problem first and see.

Answer (score 0):

copy and edited the wrong line.

just to be clear
When you mean to allow access to /usr/bind/zones you have to not
copy and edit /var/bind to create /var/bind/zones.

I also changed the secondary server to format all files at text, it had been
hit and miss but now its all text.

To be clear, dump editing error in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.bind

I don't believe the second change had anything to do with the error I'd seen.

Closing the issue as I'm now restarting named cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - now I have it.
Conflicts between my include for static and dynamic files, some duplication.
Corrected path for /etc/bind/zones, and with this test server acting as secondary for dynamic zones I needed to allow links in apparmor, /etc/bind/zones/** lrw
Also I was missing trailing dots and parenthesis for some zones.

Overall my replacement server is far far better configured then the older VM its replacing.